# Loading a library in Gradle using JitPack

Tags: android, git, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jitpack

I am working on an Android project, I use the MPChart library from Github.
For now I have a folder on my project with all the source code of the library, but I want to load it using Gradle instead.
I found a tool to get a Git repository into your build called JitPack (jitpack.io)
So I added this line to my Build.Gradle file :

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.5'
}
```

The problem is I think the user changed his name, so I used to import the library using :

```
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.ScatterChart;
```

(Notice the difference : PhilJay / mikephil)

So when I delete the folder containing the library the build doesn't work.

Can someone help me load the library using Gradle/Jitpack ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to add the repository:

```
repositories { 
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
```

Then you have to check the name of the user and the repo to add the dependency:

```
 dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.User:Repo:Tag'
   }
```

In your case it seems to be correct. (the v2.1.5 is not the latest version but [it exists](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/v2.1.5))

```
compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.1.5'
```

More info [here](https://jitpack.io/docs/).